# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/")

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to delete a railsv5 record form a vue.js app. It gets deleted but rails returns `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/"):` and I don't get why?

Rails Server outputs `Started DELETE "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-06 10:28:50 +0100` in the console but why does it redirect to "/" via delete?

**Delete Request**

```
deleteOffer() {
    axios.delete(`/offers/${this.$route.params.id}.json`, {
        data: {
            id: this.offer.id,
            authenticity_token: document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content")
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(repsonse)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.errors.push(error)
            console.log("[ERROR] Delete Offer from Rails: " + error.message);
        });
}
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'app#index'
  resources :offers
end
```

**Controller**

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController
  # DELETE /offers/1.json
  def destroy
    @offer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => {status: 'deleted'}, status: :deleted }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Apparently `this.$route.params.id` in your JS returns `undefined`, `null` or something like this. You probably need to put `debugger` in your JS code and see what happens.

Comment: It actually works, so the right record gets deleted and this.$route.params.id returns the correct value. @MarcelLipka